# How to define top and left points from a cropped numpy rectangle?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, rectangles

Good day, in following code, I am able to crop a rectangle ROI from the first frame.
The final outcome of this while loop provided an ROI stored as numpy array named "monitor_region".

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture("Rob.mp4")       
ret, frame = video.read()
roi_status = False

while(roi_status == False):
    roi = cv2.selectROI("Region Selection by ROI", frame, False)
    if(not all(roi)):
        print("Undefined monitor region.")
        continue
    monitor_region = frame[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]),int(roi[0]):int(roi[0]+roi[2])]
    cv2.imshow("Selected Region", monitor_region)
    if(cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == 8): #backspace to save
        print("Monitor region has been saved.")
        roi_status = True
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Since this "monitor_region" is a portion of entire frame as well as a rectangle. Therefore, I am looking for a feasible solution to define its left and top points in order to define a range for checking (As illustration provided). In following code, I am able to define and width and height of the roi.

```
monitor_width = monitor_region.shape[1]
monitor_height = monitor_region.shape[0]
```

[image]

However, I am still lack of left and top points. Once I have obtained both top and left points of ROI. I could perform x and y points checking in as below, which I use to determine if the object exists within ROI or not.

```
if((monitor_left < Point_x < (monitor_left + monitor_width)) and (monitor_top < Point_y < (monitor_top + monitor_height))):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectROI` returns a tuple of exactly the values you seek: the left bound, the top bound, the width and the height of the selected ROI.

If you `print(roi)` you will get something like `(100,150,300,200)`

You can unpack the values like this:

```
x,y,width,height = roi
```

Where x is the left bound and y is the top bound.